# Doctrine: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: dql

I have a Subscribers table which consists of emails (not unique) and a category for each email.
I am trying to find the emails for each category using the following function but get the error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

This is my function:

```
public function findEmailsByCategory($category)
{

     $result = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
        'SELECT s.email FROM NEWSBlogBundle:Subscribers s WHERE s.category =:category'
    )->getResult();


    return $result;

}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specified "category" parameter value. Please see [Doctrine DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) usage.

ex.

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM ForumUser u WHERE u.username = :name');
$query->setParameter('name', 'Bob'); // you didn't add required parameter.
$users = $query->getResult();
```